# "application trying to modify system" screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows

Sorry for a vague question, but I am no Windows user.

By default it seems that Windows 7 has this dialog popup that pops up everytime I start an application that wants to modify some settings. (since I am no regular Windows user I can not remember what this concept is called).

A couple of days ago I managed to click the "change settings" link in this dialog and dragged the slider to the bottom (saying something like never nag again).

Now I want to reset this to the default setting, but I can't find the settings anywhere yet.

Anyone who knows where this setting can be found.

Again, sorry for the vague description. Hope somebody knows what I am talking about

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Hit the META key (the one with the Windows Logo on the key), type "UAC". This search brings up "User Account Control Settings" - select that, and there's your slider. :) (Default is the second from the top)